# Enforce subclass to declare a enum

Tags: java, generics, enums, subclass

Can I enforce child classes to create a enum in them?

```
class Document<T extends Enum<T>>{
    Map<T, String> fields;
}
class TextDocument extends Document<TextDocument.Field>{
    public enum Field{
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I enforce any implementation of Document to have an enum named Field within it? In the above example, TextDocument can extend Document with some other enum (say GraphDocument.Field) as well which shouldn't be allowed. How can I create this restriction? I need to enforce this rule to subclasses - "You must have your own enum". Is this even possible? By some hacky way? Any ideas?

Comment: You can use reflection

Comment: Can you please give a small example?

Comment: Try to load the enum of the other class (by calling `getClass().getXxx`) and if you don't find throw an Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't. However, you can force it to return an array of the values of a particular enumeration. You can also force the enumeration to implement an interface.

```
public interface SomeInterface {
  // any methods you want to be able to perform on the enums
}

public abstract class SomeSuperClass<T extends SomeInterface> {
  abstract T[] getSome();
}

public class SomeSubclass extends SomeSuperClass<SomeInterface> {
    public enum SomeEnum implements SomeInterface {
      testEnum {
        // interface implementation
      }
    }

    public SomeInterface[] getSome() {
        return SomeEnum.values();
    }
}
```

This is a pretty awkward solution, but it works.

Comment: How does Serializable expect a variable that should be public, static, final and long to be declared? Though its not enforcement, its atleast showing up with yellow mark in eclipse. I need to replicate such behaviour. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didn't know about these eclipse warnings, as I had an impression that these are java compiler warnings.